# Right-to-Left full contents on a PHP Website

Tags: php, html, css

I have a Help Desk Support in my website and i want to change all the content of this help desk to RTL . by default , its LTR.
i have tried this code in my `index.php` :

```
<style> body, html {
direction:rtl !important;}
</style>
```

but it didn't change the direction of the Login form and etc.

Comment: Have you tried cache refresh? (e.g. CTRL+F5 in chrome on windows)

Comment: freehelpdesk.org , i use this and i want to make the website full RLT because i translate all the site to Persian ( Farsi) and now i want the whole site to be RLT . There is a Form in index.php and i have includes/all-nav.php which is my navigation bar and this navigation bar didn't change the direction from LTR to RLT

Answer (score 1):

Add `unicode-bidi` property with value `bidi-override`.

```
* {direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xyz04r76/

Comment: not worked . i downloaded a RTL Bootstrap css file and it fixed the problem . but i want some bootswatch themes with RLT fix. any helps?

Comment: @Aria: please be more specific what means _not worked_? Did you see my fiddle? You should see rtl aligned text.